# xpath problem with quotes " (python+selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, double-quotes

I'm creating a Whatsapp bot and in part of my code I get the chat name and search for it with xpath with:

(ttt is a str variable)(html source is from 'https://web.whatsapp.com')

`self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@title,'"+ttt+"')]")`

But I have had problem with apostrophe ' and I solve it with:

`self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[contains(@title,\""+ttt+"\")]")`

Now my str variable have double quotes " (as in 'ce"roo'). How should I write my xpath to get it? (I want to get it in apostrophe cases and in double quotes cases). I have searched a lot in internet, and I haven't found nothing that work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using single quotes inside the xpath and also using %-formatting.Example:

```
ttt = 'ce"roo'
xpath = ".//span[contains(@title,'%s')]" % ttt
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
```

See [Escaping XPath literal with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937525/escaping-xpath-literal-with-python/6938681) on how to escape single apostrophes.

Comment: Thank's, you almost solve it. It works for double quotes, but don't work anymore for apostrophe.

Comment: Thank's again, but now It doesn't work neither for double quotes nor for apostrophe. (I have done the .replace.replace and your code box.

Comment: Seems the problem lies with escaping apostrophes in xpath; see the answer to the following question for a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937525/escaping-xpath-literal-with-python/6938681

Comment: Thank's man! I have done something similar with if's (with your answer help). If nobody answer me a solution without if's or better, I will give you the best answer.